# VB.NET equivalent of {} nesting

Tags: vb.net, scope

Does VB.NET have any scope nesting operators like {} in C type languages?

Example C++ type code:

```
int i;
i = 0;
{
  int i;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: What is that chunk of code supposed to do?  It makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Josh - If I am remembering correctly, it is defining another scope for the second "i" that is being declared. Thus, the "i" outside of the block will retain the value of 0 even though the one in the block will be 1.

Comment: The real question is why do you want to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, VB.Net has no such blanket scoping modifiers.  You can simulate them by using an empty loop like the following.

```
Loop
  ...
Until False
```

However it will still not permit you to redefine a variable with the same name.  In VB.Net (and C#) it is not legal to define a variable in a nested scope with the same name as a variable in an outer scope.

Comment: IMO it's good not to have this: 9 times out of 10 it means that could should be in it's own method anyway.

Comment: @Joel, completely agree.  I've been bitten several times by double defined variables in C++.  It's especially problematic in old code bases with very large methods which have been patch worked for years.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an empty [`With` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx):

```
With Nothing

    Dim x = 1

    Console.WriteLine("X = " + x.ToString())

End With

' ERROR! x is out of scope at this point. '
Console.WriteLine(x)
```

Since `With` is only a syntactic sugar it might be better than using looping statements.